# LIKE operator within an IN clause in Dataloader

Tags: soql, data-loader, data

I'm using Data Loader to extract some data and I'm running into an issue.  I have a bunch of values that I want to run a LIKE query against, but I basically want to do a like with and IN clause.  So my code is:

```
SELECT ID, PREF from CONTACT WHERE PREF=BBB% OR PREF=JJJ%)
```

The catch seems to be, this works just find on regular text fields, but the data I'm querying is a multi-pick list so I'm getting the old 'cannot bind' error.   I'm new to SOQL and a little out of my depth especially using data loader, so I appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Since you commented that you're having problems using the data loader, make sure you read the [Salesforce Object Query Language (SOQL)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm) documentation. It has everything you need to know.

Answer (score 2):

LIKE operator is not supported in Multi-select picklist.

You need to use `INCLUDES` keyword to compare and listing

```
WHERE MultiSelectField__c includes ('BBB') OR MultiSelectField__c includes ('JJJ')
```

Refer [Querying Multi-Select Picklists](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_querying_multiselect_picklists.htm)

Secondly, if multi-select picklist entry is `Billing` then you need to specify `MultiSelectField__c includes ('Billing')` as `MultiSelectField__c includes ('Billin%')` doesn't return matching the records.